# how to retrieve information about web services

Tags: android, web-services, service-discovery

I have been working on this project for months and I am getting desperate.

I have done research and relied on papers that talked about the user-provider-uddi architecture, so my purpose was the following:

through a mobile app, the user would write a keyword of needed web services, the query and the user's and device profile would both be sent to a middleware. Now the middleware is supposed to get a list of services of the same category as the keyword and compare the web services information to the user and device profile.

**For example**: it will check the required cpu, memory, screen size, language, location where it works and type of display (graphic/text) and compare it to the device specifications and user's preferences to select the best services.

---

**Now my problem is:**

1. I can't find any public repository (all those mentioned in other posts do not exist anymore)
2. assuming that I can use an interface (such as JAXR) to get services by category, how can I get the context-related information about services (cpu/memory requirements, language, location, display etc...). would that be possible through JAXR ? Is there a document that describes this about Web services (just like wsdl describe functions?)
3. what is the common was used to search for web services from a mobile nowadays ?

I know the question is somehow general, but I really worked a lot on this and I'm stuck. If there are people who specialize in the domain, please let me know your opinion. I would like some practical answers that can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are still a few public repositories out there (e.g., [Service Repository](http://www.service-repository.com/)). It is true that most of the web services you will find are not available anymore, but you can create your own service repository and deploy it either locally or somewhere in the cloud. It is basically just a hash map (service id mapped to a service uri?) and you can use any database to store the data.
2. Context information usually comes in different types. You have user context, service context, system context, environment context. Usually this information is embedded in the service response messages to the service consumer. Anything that can store data can be used to store this context. It's basically just data. Also, it can be collected when the request comes, but it will introduce a certain delay when serving the request. A proactive approach should be considered here.

[image: Context added to provide response]

3. This is very general. Depends on the type of service you're interested in. I believe the common approach to query a cloud based registry is the standard.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for the answer. I looked more into that and I still have some questions. I hope you will have the kindness to answer again at the best of your knowledge.

For the public repository, I already checked it, but most of the services were not working. Plus, it does not store enough services of the same kind, hence can't be used for testing. 

How is the information embedded in the service response? So far, I couldn't find how that data is or can be represented. Should I just make up context data for each service, or is there a way to find real context data for each service?